# Geopackage vector data type

Tags: python, geopackage, floating-point

I am reading a shapefile in Python using geopandas, join some tabular data and export to geopackage using geopandas.

The entire process is very easy. However, when I export the vector data, the file is quite large and contains unnecessary details. Comparing the process to raster data, I can choose a data type e.g. Unsigned Integer 32, Float 64, Boolean etc.

Is there something similar for the geopackage format? Currently my vertices have the following format (examaple of one coordinate, file contains multipolygons): 
`31.90590570688292, 29.85788703615783`

How can I store the vertices using 32bit precision for each coordinate? Ideally the answer would be in python (and geopandas / fiona)

Comment: GeoPackage standard http://www.geopackage.org/spec121/index.html#gpb_format defines that geometries are stored as Well Known Binary http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355. Thus coordinates are internally stored as doubles.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, great. Do I understand correctly, that double is always 8 bytes i.e. 64 bit and that ther there is currently no way to "force" using less bytes for each point ? This is superfluous for my application. Maybe I should consider a different format.

Comment: Shapefiles use [Int32 to store geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_shape_format_(.shp)), see if that reduces the file size.

Comment: Perhaps Tiny WKB is already used somewhere together with SQLite database https://github.com/TWKB/Specification/blob/master/twkb.md. GeoPackage will not adopt it before higher level OGC standard appears https://github.com/opengeospatial/geopackage/issues/365.